# Clipping with Python gdal warp gives no output

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, clip

I clipped a TIFF file using gdal warp, but it is not giving out any output clipped raster. I need help in finding why it does this and how to correct this.

```
import gdal

ras_in=gdal.Open('C:/Users/Lake.tif')
shp_in="C:/Users/mypo.shp"
ras_out='C:/Users/Lake_clip.tif'

result=gdal.Warp(ras_out,ras_in,cutlineDSName=shp_in,cropToCutline=True,dstNodata=0)
result=None
```

I updated the gdal version based on the idea given here at stack exchange. Now new problem - the output clipped raster has 0 in it completely, it is just blank.

Comment: Works for me with the data from your previous question `from osgeo import gdal
ras_in=gdal.Open('montreal_500m.tif')
shp_in="Montreal_buffer.json"
ras_out='out.tif'
result=gdal.Warp(ras_out,ras_in,cutlineDSName=shp_in,cropToCutline=True,dstNodata=0)`. Does your shapefile intersect with your raster? You seem to use an old syntax in `import gdal`. Is your GDAL version old as well? The current version is 3.6.0.

Comment: @user30184 Great I updated gdal my version and it works and gives an output. But a new error pops up where the output has no data; it is completely blank.

Comment: @user30184 As you suggested the shapefile didn't intersect with the raster hence the output was blank. Managed to get the proper output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from osgeo import gdal

ras_in=('C:/Users/Lake.tif')
shp_in="C:/Users/mypo.shp"
ras_out='C:/Users/Lake_clip.tif'

result = gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = ras_in, 
                   destNameOrDestDS = ras_out, 
                   cutlineDSName    = shp_in,
                   cropToCutline    = True,
                   dstNodata        = 0)
result = None

### You don't need to use  '''gdal.Open'''
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, my gdal version was an older one and secondly, the shapefile and then the raster did not intersect, which is why the error occurred.